# What is the translation of מתא הוא ואיכא טובא: ? and SAY"D 334.44

Tags: translation

I'm learning [SAY"D #334.44](https://en.wikisource.org/wiki/Translation:Shulchan_Aruch/Yoreh_Deah/334#43) and I have some difficulty in translation.
Particularly two expressions that both happen to have have "meta" or "mayytei."
Below is what I have so far.
Any help or corrections appreciated.

44

A chakham who ruled to permit [remarriage of a woman whose husband is alleged to have drowned] in unbounded water, is liable nidui. So too whoever transgresses his neder/ oath.

And any beit dit that relies on him for questions, **unless he's dead. [? bar sh'meta hu]**

Also those who perform labor whilst there is a corpse it town that is still not buried: they are liable nidui, unless there are [burial] teams in town.

Also whoever makes leniencies or stringencies, or a gezeira shawah to uproot a thing from the Torah, or who asks an impossible question.

Also whoever is wary of his fellow in some matter and turns him in to the king or judge, we ostracize him till he **comes forth [? maytei]** and stands in beit din.

Also a talmid chakham who holds fast in a dispute against the majority. Also whoever gives a ruling in place of his rav.

> סעיף מד >>   חכם שהורה להתיר במים שאין להם סוף חייב נידוי וכן מי שעובר על נדרו וכל בית דין שנזקק לו לשאלה **בר שמתא הוא** וכן העושים מלאכה בעוד שיש מת בעיר ועדיין לא נקבר חייבים נידוי אא"כ יש חבורות בעיר וכן מי שעושה קלים וחמורים או גזירה שוה לעקור דבר מן התורה או שואל דבר שאי אפשר וכן מי שיש לו עירעור על חבירו בדבר אחד ומוסר אותו למלך או לשופט משמתין ליה עד **דמייתי ליה** וקיימי בבית דין וכן תלמיד חכם המחזיק במחלוקת כנגד הרבים וכן המורה הוראה במקום רבו.

Comment: https://www.hebrewbooks.org/rambam.aspx?mfid=33207&rid=228   Rambam Talmud Torah 6:14 Raavad has a fuller expression  בר שמתא הוא ואיכא טובא:

Comment: Would they write a letter calling for him to come forth or send emissaries?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The first expression "בר שמתא הוא" seems to be "*bar *shamta* hu*" i.e. he warrants excommunication/ostracism.

See, e.g. [Jastrow](https://en.wikisource.org/wiki/A_Dictionary_of_the_Targumim,_the_Talmud_Babli_and_Yerushalmi,_and_the_Midrashic_Literature/%D7%A9%D7%9E%D7%A9%D7%95%D7%9A_-_%D7%A9%D7%A0%D7%90):

> ‎שמתא, ‎שמתא, ‎שמתא ‎f. ‎(preced.) ‎[desolation,] ‎1) ‎curse, ‎ban. ‎Targ. ‎Y. ‎Gen. ‎XLII, ‎37. ‎Targ. ‎Y. ‎Num. ‎XXI, ‎24. ‎Targ. ‎Cant. ‎II, ‎16. ‎-- ‎M. ‎Kat. ‎17a ‎ש׳ ‎מאי ‎what ‎is ‎(the ‎etymology ‎of) ‎shammta?h ‎Rab ‎said ‎מיתה ‎שם ‎there ‎is ‎death; ‎Samuel ‎said, ‎יהיה ‎שממה ‎(Ms. ‎M. ‎שמה; ‎Ar. ‎שם ‎תהא, ‎read; ‎תהא ‎שמה) ‎he ‎shall ‎be ‎(be ‎thou) ‎a ‎desolation. ‎Ib. ‎בש׳ ‎גברא ‎האי ‎ליהוי ‎that ‎man ‎(thou) ‎be ‎excommunicat- ‎ed. ‎Ib. ‎16a ‎וכ׳ ‎עליה ‎ש׳ ‎חל ‎לא ‎(masc.) ‎the ‎ban ‎has ‎not ‎yet ‎rested ‎on ‎him ‎thirty ‎days. ‎Ib. ‎וכ׳ ‎ש׳ ‎דחיילא ‎עד ‎(it ‎cannot ‎be ‎raised) ‎before ‎he ‎has ‎been ‎under ‎the ‎ban ‎thirty ‎days. ‎Sot. ‎5a ‎ביה ‎דלית ‎ובש׳ ‎ביה ‎דאית ‎בש׳ ‎he ‎(the ‎scholar) ‎in ‎whom ‎there ‎is ‎pride ‎deserves ‎excommunication, ‎and ‎also ‎he ‎in ‎whom ‎there ‎is ‎no ‎pride ‎at ‎all. ‎Kidd. ‎12b ‎Rab ‎ordered ‎to ‎be ‎lashed ‎וכ׳ ‎ש׳ ‎דחלא ‎על ‎him ‎who ‎allowed ‎excommunication ‎(for ‎contempt ‎of ‎court) ‎to ‎rest ‎on ‎him ‎thirty ‎days ‎(and ‎did ‎not ‎submit ‎to ‎authority). ‎B. ‎Mets. ‎70a ‎דרבנן ‎ש׳ ‎עליה ‎מקבל ‎ולא ‎Ms. ‎M. ‎and ‎does ‎not ‎bring ‎upon ‎himself ‎the ‎ban ‎of ‎the ‎Rabbis ‎(but ‎obeys ‎their ‎summons); ‎a. ‎fr. ‎- ‎2) ‎י ‎h. ‎חרם, ‎accursed ‎oyect. ‎Targ. ‎Y. ‎Deut. ‎XIII, ‎18. ‎-- ‎Pl. ‎שמתין. ‎Ib. ‎VII, ‎26, ‎v. ‎שמיתא.

See also, e.g., [here](https://www.torahmusings.com/2020/08/the-restrictions-of-nidui/) and [here](https://dafyomi.co.il/nedarim/discuss/nd-qa-007.2.htm) for possible distinction between *shamta* and *nidui*.

2. The latter expression "עד דמייתי ליה וקיימי בבית דין" seems to mean: "until they bring him and they stand in court".

See [Jastrow](https://www.sefaria.org/Shulchan_Arukh%2C_Yoreh_De%27ah.334.44?lang=bi&with=all&lang2=en&p3=Jastrow%2C_*%D7%90%D6%B8%D7%AA%D6%B8%D7%90_III&lang3=en):

> אֲתָא, אָתָא II ch. (b. h. אתה, אתא; sec. r. of אוֹת I q. v.) [to join,] to come, to arrive; to occur to. Targ. Gen. XIX, 9; a. fr.—Y. Peah III, 17ᵈ bot. אתאי עובדא וכ׳ the case came before … Gen. R. s. 68 (ref. to Gen. XXVIII, 11) א׳ שמשא the Sun (Jacob) has arrived. Snh. 98ᵇ יֵיתֵי ולא איחמיניה he (the Messiah) will come, but I do not desire to live to see him (to pass through the trials preceding his arrival).—תֵּיתֵי לי ד־ may it come home to me that I did—, i.e. I believe to have merited divine reward. Meg. 28ᵃ; a. fr.—ייתי עלי דלא may it come home to me that I did not—; a formula of assurance, surely, indeed. Y. Ber. II, 5ᶜ bot.; a. fr.; (v. יבוא עלי, s. v. בּוֹא).—Y. Shebi. VI, 36ᶜ top ייתי ד־ (sub. עלי).—Imperat. תָּא (Y. אִיתָא). Gitt. 57ᵃ, a. fr. תא חזי; Y. Dem. VI, 25ᵇ top איתא חמי; in Bab. usu. תא שמע (abbr. ת"ש) come and see, come and hear, i.e. I will prove it.—אַתְיָא כ־ it comes like, i.e. it is in accordance with the opinion of.—Y. Naz. VI, 54ᵈ bot.; a. v. fr.—וַתְּיָיא = ואתיא. Ibid.ᶜ bot. ותייא כהדא דתני חזקיה (ed. Krot. incorr. ותניא) תִּי.—Y. Keth. IV, 28ᵈ top ותאיין וכ׳ (read ואתיין) and those differences of opinion correspond to …—אתיא פקידה פקידה the expression pakad occurs in two Biblical passages, אתיא זכירה זכירה and the expression zakhar occurs in two passages, i.e. draw an analogy between the respective Bible laws in which the same expressions are used, so as to cast a light upon each other. R. Hash. 11ᵃ; a. fr. [אתא נסיא Y. Meg. II, 73ᵇ, a. e., read אֲתָאנַסְיָא q. v.] [Targ. Y. II, Deut. XXXIII, 16 יַתְיַן, 3rd pers. fem. fut.]
>     Af. - אַיְתִי, אֵיתִי, , אַיְיתִי to bring, carry, cause to come. Targ. Gen. IV, 3; a. fr.—מנא תיתי (מהיכא, מנן) whence wilt thou bring (evidence), how will you prove it? Y. B. Mets. III, beg. 9ᵃ; a. v. fr.—מַיְיתָה, מַיְיתִי, מֵיתֵי bringing, to bring. Y. Peah I, 15ᶜ top בעי מ׳ וכ׳ he desired to bring it to them. Ib. לא יכילת מייתותי׳ I cannot bring it.—לַיְיתֵי, לֵיְתֵי let him bring. Sabb. 109ᵇ; a. fr.—לאַיְתוּיֵי, לַאֲתוּיֵי (cmp. אֵת) to bring in, to include, opp. לאפוקי; v. אַפֵּק. לא׳ מאי what is to be implied (in addition to what is explicitly stated)? Tem. 2ᵃ הכל לאי׳ מאי what does hakkol (all) come to imply? a. fr.—Haf. הַיְיתִי same. Dan. V, 13; a. e.
>     Ittaf. - אִתֵּיתִי (אִתּוֹתִי, אִתַּתִי) to be brought, offered. Targ. Gen. XXXIII, 11. Targ. Lev. XIII, 2; a. e.

Comment: So what's the longer expression here, "Deserves ostracism and there's good [what?]"
hebrewbooks.org/rambam.aspx?mfid=33207&rid=228 Rambam Talmud Torah 6:14 Raavad  בר שמתא הוא ואיכא טובא

Comment: "he is one who should be ostracized and there are many other [examples]". טובא can mean "many".  see e.g. jastrow https://www.sefaria.org/Jastrow%2C_%D7%98%D7%95%D6%BC%D7%91%D6%B8%D7%90.1?lang=bi&with=all&lang2=en see also sefaria's translation of the raavad: https://www.sefaria.org/Hasagot_HaRaavad_on_Mishneh_Torah%2C_Torah_Study.6.14?lang=bi